# How can I speed up this SQLAlchemy Query? In FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have Volunteers table and it has 60 fields, I use FastAPI and SQLalchemy ORM:

```
class Volunteers(Base):
    __tablename__ = "volunteers"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    candidate_id = Column(Integer)
    full_name = Column(String)
......
```

And I have function where I import excel file and write data from excel to database. I import all users from excel to *all_users_in_excel* list. *all_users_in_excel* is a list of dictionaries. Dictionaries include each user information. Then I get one user at a time from *all_users_in_excel* list and create new_user object with values and append it to a new list.

```
def import_data(file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    all_users_in_excel = []
    with open(f'{file.filename}', "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)

    volunteer_data = pd.read_excel("assignment-data.xlsx", index_col=None)
    
    for name in volunteer_data.iterrows():  
        new_user_from_excel = name[1].to_dict()
        all_users_in_excel.append(new_user_from_excel)

    saved_users = []
    for key in all_users_in_excel:
                new_user = {
                "candidate_id": key["Candidate - ID"],
                "full_name": key["Candidate - Full Name"],
                "checkpoint": key["Candidate - Checkpoint"],
                ..... 
                "created_at": datetime.now()
                }
                saved_users.append(new_user)
        
    db.bulk_insert_mappings(models.Volunteers, saved_users)
    db.commit()
```

db.bulk_insert_mappings(models.Volunteers, saved_users) takes **20 seconds to save 110** users. How can I speed it up? I use Postgresql as a database and it is deployed to Heroku free subscription.

Comment: Start by using a profiler to see _what is taking up your time_. If you spend 19.5 seconds to parse the excel file, that's where you should start looking.

Comment: I have already checked it, it takes 1 second to parse the excel file

Comment: So is the rest of the time spent in `bulk_insert_mapping`? I'm not familiar with the performance of SQL on the free Heroku subscription, so I'm not sure what the baseline should be.

Comment: Yes, bulk_insert_mapping takes 20 seconds

Comment: As noted in [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_insert_mappings#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_insert_mappings): "It is **strongly recommended** to not use the bulk methods as they represent a forking of SQLAlchemy’s functionality and are slowly being moved into legacy status." (Emphasis theirs.)